# Git - remove seed repo's history from commit history

Tags: git, revision-history

My github pages repo is based on https://github.com/maciakl/Sample-Jekyll-Site. To achieve this I cloned https://github.com/maciakl/Sample-Jekyll-Site then manually changed the origin in git config. But now my repo has all https://github.com/maciakl/Sample-Jekyll-Site's commits in its history. Is there a way I can get rid of them?

Comment: You want to clone from another repository, without acutally cloning the repository? Copying the commit history *is what cloning does*. What else did you want to happen?

Comment: @jalf - I see your point but, on the other hand, including the sample site I cloned is somewhat akin to using e.g. a snippet in my IDE (albeit a huge, multi-file snippet) and including its history feels like unnecessary clutter. I'm not developing the sample site, just using it as a tool which I accept as it is in its present  state.

Comment: GitHub repos are lightweight, and while you might not necessarily need it, there is no problem in keeping the original history. It could also come in handy if you want to contribute back to the sample repo or revert individual commits from the sample repo in your new repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone with depth 1. This will get you the current state of the repo, without any history.

However, it is questionable if this is really what you should do - in general, the commit history contains a lot of valuable information.